# How to add Shapefile to map?

Tags: shapefile, esri

**What's The NameSpace for ShapeFile Class ?**

my language is silverlight in Esri Map:

```
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer ShowLegend="false" ID="ResultsGraphicsLayer" />
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer ShowLegend="false" ID="MyGraphicsLayer" />
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer ShowLegend="false" ID="MySelectionGraphicsLayer" MouseEnter="GraphicsLayer_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="GraphicsLayer_MouseLeave"/>
                        <esri:GraphicsLayer ShowLegend="false" ID="IdentifyIconGraphicsLayer"/>

                    </esri:Map>
```

in codebehind:

private void openFileDialog_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
        {
            //Create the dialog allowing the user to select the "*.shp" and the "*.dbf" files
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Multiselect = true;

```
        if( !( ofd.ShowDialog() ?? false ) )
            return;

        //Get the file info objects for the SHP and the DBF file selected by the user
        FileInfo shapeFile = null;
        FileInfo dbfFile = null;
        foreach( FileInfo fi in ofd.Files )
        {
            if( fi.Extension.ToLower() == ".shp" )
            {
                shapeFile = fi;
            }
            if( fi.Extension.ToLower() == ".dbf" )
            {
                dbfFile = fi;
            }
        }

        //Read the SHP and DBF files into the ShapeFileReader
        ShapeFile shapeFileReader = new ShapeFile();
        if( shapeFile != null && dbfFile != null )
        {
            shapeFileReader.Read( shapeFile, dbfFile );
        }
        else
        {
            HtmlPage.Window.Alert( "Please select a SP and a DBF file to proceed." );
            return;
        }

        //Add the shapes from the shapefile into a graphics layer named "shapefileGraphicsLayer"
        //the greaphics layer should be present in the XAML or created earlier
        GraphicsLayer graphicsLayer = MyMap.Layers[ "shapefileGraphicsLayer" ] as GraphicsLayer;
        foreach( ShapeFileRecord record in shapeFileReader.Records )
        {
            Graphic graphic = record.ToGraphic();
            if( graphic != null )
                graphicsLayer.Graphics.Add( graphic );
        }
```

Comment: This is really just a codeblock, and it's not clear where _exactly_ you are having a problem. Is there an error? Is it simply not working? Have you not figured out how to write the rest of the code? What language are you working in (I can tell from the code, but _be specific_!) This needs significant clarification unfortunately -- sorry.

Comment: My language  is Silverlight and I am using  Esri Map , I want add shapefile to Map when that edited, i get this code from internet but in silverlight dont know Shapefile